# Using img src as Navbar Brand

Tags: css, image, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm having an issue with my Bootstrap v4.5.0 navbar. I want to use a logo as the navbar brand. I want it to be treated exactly as if it were HTML text. However, I can't seem to figure out how to replicate it. Note that my navbar has other items besides just the brand, and that for some reason, the img pushes the "Home" and "New Record" links all the way on the right side of the bar when these 2 items should be directly next to the logo. I've adjusted the padding and other CSS items to try to resolve this with no l When I shrink the window, I want the img to stay the same size, but as of now it shrinks. So, to recap, my 2 issues are: 1. incorrect padding of other navbar links next to logo, and 2. resizing of logo based on window size. I want to make the img behave as close to plain HTML text as possible. Thanks for any assistance! I've attached an image of my page to illustrate some problems. Notice the resizing of the logo as well as the incorrect placement of "Home" and "New Record".

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img id="logo" alt="Logo" src="${contextRoot}/img/bcore-bride+AI.png" width=8% height=8% />
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="${contextRoot}/" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="${contextRoot}/newRecord" class="nav-link">New Record</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" style="float: right">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="${contextRoot}/account">My Account</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image: examples of problems I'm experiencing]

Answer (score 0):

The incorrect placement of home and new record is because of you put those into different  tag from my account. And use margin left auto so it will get cover all the extra space and push your icon to the right.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my intended placement. I want the logo and both "Home" and "New Record" on the left side of the page while "My Account" is on the right.

Comment: Then use margin-right: auto on first pair of ul. It will cover all the space on the right side

Comment: I posted an answer to what gave me the best result. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the desired outcome with the following:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img id="logo" alt="Logo" src="${contextRoot}/img/bcore-bride+AI.png" width="80" height="25" />
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="${contextRoot}/" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="${contextRoot}/newRecord" class="nav-link">New Record</a></li>
        </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="${contextRoot}/account">My Account</a></li>
            </ul> 
    </div>
</nav>
```

I was able to hard set the logo to a certain pixel size (which I dislike the idea of for reasons of inflexibility). Also, I set ml-auto for the collapsible button and "My Account", and mr-auto for "Home" and "New Record".